# Sort strings in original order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is the query i am using:

```
;WITH list (Value) AS
(
SELECT Value
        FROM (
        SELECT Value
        FROM fn_SplitString('Quick Brown Fox',' ')
        ) a
), cte AS
(
    SELECT Value
    FROM list
    UNION ALL
    SELECT two.Value + ' ' + one.Value 
    FROM cte AS one, list AS two
    WHERE two.Value > one.Value
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
```

The **output** of that will be

```
Quick
Brown
Fox
Quick Fox
Quick Brown
Fox Brown
Quick Fox Brown
```

The **fn_SplitString** will create a table like this. It will just split all the words separated by spaces into rows.

```
Quick
Brown
Fox
```

I already tried reversing it using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GETDATE())` and this will be the output of **fn_SplitString**. But still the overall output will be the same.

```
Fox 
Brown 
Quick
```

the query above sorts the words/letters **alphabetically(reversed)** per row and what output i need is not sorted alphabetically or like the example below.

**Expected Output**

```
Quick
Brown
Fox
Quick Brown
Quick Fox
Brown Fox
Quick Brown Fox
```

or

```
Quick Brown Fox
Quick Brown
Quick Fox
Brown Fox
Quick
Brown
Fox
```

**how will I do that?**

Comment: What is the rule for `C A B` to be in this particular order?

Comment: 1st word will be first, last word will be the last.
ex:

"quick brown fox"
`  
quick 
brown 
fox
quick brown
brown fox 
quick fox
quick brown fox
`

Comment: We need to see how fn_SplitString emits the parsed data. It should be able to return an index to you that you can use later to sort

Comment: @NathanSkerl i'll edit the post.

Comment: @a_enriquez Thanks, it would help to see the code of the function

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to either modify `fn_SplitString` to return an indexer or switch to using a different split string function that returns one ([example](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=76033&whichpage=2)), but in either case **you need to get the sort index from that parse operation**.

EDIT: The order of the insert into @Stage below is not reliable without an explicit `ORDER BY` as commented by damien. Ill leave the example here but it does not serve the OP's purpose:

```
declare @stage table (i int identity(1,1) primary key, value varchar(max));
insert into @stage (value)
    select Value from dbo.fn_SplitString('Quick Brown Fox',' ');

;WITH list (i, Value) AS
(
    SELECT [i] = cast(i as varchar(10)), Value
    FROM @stage
), cte (i, value) AS 
(
    SELECT  cast(i as varchar(10)), 
            Value
    FROM list AS wan
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  cast(two.i + '/' + one.i as varchar(10)), 
            two.Value + ' ' + one.Value 
    FROM cte AS one, list AS two
    WHERE two.Value > one.Value
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
order by len(i), i;
```

Here, ive constructed "i" as an node path ("1/2/3") just to illustrate whats going on in your CTE. You can of course order this anyway you want using i.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I executed the query you created and the output is
1 Quick
2 Brown
3 Fox
1/2 Quick Brown
1/3 Quick Fox
3/2 Fox Brown
1/3/2 Quick Fox Brown

you told me that i can order it anyway i want, but how? can you please give me an example? 
i want the last output to be 1/2/3.
Thanks again

Comment: `INSERT ... SELECT` is only guaranteed to assign identity values in the "correct" order if you use an `ORDER BY` clause. But in order to have that, we again return to needing the split function to give us a column we can use for that purpose.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thats exactly right... i was going to add that this would only work if fn_SplitString had an explicit order within it, but thats not possible. +1

Comment: I think i need another approach for this problem. I'll just post another question different from this. Thanks!